# how do you bevel like shown in picture

Tags: modeling, topology, bevel

[image][image: the bevel is around 1.5-2cm in thickness.]
what i have tried

1. insetting but insetting starts tearing the faces after some thickness
2. i tried beveling but i do not have idea how do i do varying bevel as shown in the picture

edit:

1. the face tearing is marked in red
2. I want to inset the face and modify it along the blue lines (how do I do this?)
3. the bevel thickeness of inset is 3cm in thickness

Comment: Proportional editing might be helpful here.

Comment: If you have still problems it might be a good idea to add a screenshot of what you have done so far. It's not clear to me where you want to bevel it honestly.

Comment: i have added a picture, please check it out

Answer (score -1):

There are many options. Use a Curve and parent it to faces, modify in Editmode and extrude with curvemodifier.
Or use Subdivision surface modifier and bevel it out, after mesh and scale a cube with 4 Faces. (Delete front/backface)

Comment: I'm new to blender, could you be a bit more clear (a small gif would be of great help)

Comment: @arjunlokesh : don‘t worry. I have a bit experience in Blender and I don’t understand it either…